# Accessing files on a apache server from USB via PHP

Tags: usb, server, file-server, file

I am trying to create a system where USB on Raspberry Pi will be auto mounted and the files can be accessed via an Apache server running over local hotspot from the same Raspberry Pi through a script written in PHP.

I am successful in all the steps and file names are visible via a local hotspot except that when the files are accessed, it is showing a 404 error.

- The `index.php` is located on `/var/www/html/index.php`
- The files are located on `/media/usb0`

I have tried changing the file permission to 777 (just to check) but nothing worked for me.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I have found it necessary to change the permissions on each file.

Comment: Isn't it accomplished by sudo chmod -R /foldername? I tried the same but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself.

The trick is: linking the the two folders by a symbolic link
Opening terminal from within the "files" folder (`/var/www/html/files` on the Pi), and  type:

```
sudo ln -s /media/usb1
```

(I was running pmount to automount and allocate the name usb1 to any USB attached to Pi.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score -1):

Bonjour,

Comment as-tu fais pour l'étape 1 ? je cherche à faire pareil.

Merci par avance pour ta réponse,

Jordane GUYONNET

Comment: You are not supposed to ask questions as an answer. If anything, create your own question.

Comment: please write the answer in english